# Create a screen and lock it

Tags: amiga

I want to create a custom screen and lock it in the front on AmigaOS4. It should not be possible to change the screen with any key combination or otherwise. What would be the best way to do this.

I am trying to investigate hooking into the keyboard handler somehow and disabling the <kbd>Amiga</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>or<kbd>m</kbd> for a start, but have not gotten as far yet.

I suspect that you would need to disable screen dragging as well to fully prevent a screen change from occuring.

Comment: There's a tutorial on locking the Amiga public screen here, although it's not aimed at OS4: http://www.pcguru.plus.com/tutorial/screens.html (scroll down to point 9)

Comment: There's also some explanation of how to amend the calls in the above tutorial for OS4 in another question on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510372/warning-assignment-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-a-cast-undefined-referenc